# Django static file problem. Clicking on the files downloads

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

sorry for my bad english.
My index.html file cannot find the files in the static folder. When I view the page source, I click on the css file and I get different errors from time to time. Sometimes I get 404 error when I click on css link. Sometimes when I click on the css file, it downloads the file.

Settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
 },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

 DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
  path('', include("home.urls"), name="anasayfa"),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

**Important: I'm doing my first env project, can there be a problem with the installation?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]` in settings.py before `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')`

Comment: make sure the CSS folder should be in static folder in the project directory

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]

the problem continues :(

Comment: kindly check your folder structure. is there css folder in static folder?

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'

just keep these data remove static_root

Comment: I added the folder structure to the topic now